# net Framework >= 2.0 APi

Tags: .net

i have a question to do..

The framework java give us free an API full of context of any class of they framework.

In .net is possible shared the same idea?

I never found anything, i need always to go to the internet to consult any classe or something..

Comment: What functionality do you want, exactly? The ability to print out your own MSDN library?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply find out the innards of native .NET classes, you may want to download the free version of [Red Gate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to read the code behind these classes.

There are some parts of .NET that are open sourced, e.g., [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) which you can check out as well.

Comment: basically Reflector + "print out your own MSDN library"